# How to use macro to call functions which have only suffix difference?

Tags: c, macros

In fact, I used macro to define 256 interrupt vectors, and their names are like `isr_1()`, `isr_2()` and so on. When I want to put their address to the vector array `uint32_t handlers[256]`, I faced a problem that using macro can not help my fix these problem.

```
#define ISR(NUM) isr_##NUM
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i ++){
    handlers[i] = (uint32_t)&ISR(i);
}
```

But as you know it's a wrong code. It will be expanded as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i ++){
    handlers[i] = (uint32_t)&isr_i;
}
```

There isn't any function named `isr_i()`. So it is wrong. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: The integer values are a runtime property, but what you are doing is compile time. perhaps the best thing is to create a lookup table of functions. This will be far clearer as well.  macros only throw uncertainty and poor readability into the picture.

Comment: @PaulRooney Got it, thanks!

Comment: It also wont force you to have esoteric function names like `isr_1`.

Comment: Would you like to make an answer? You seem to have the implementation of @PaulRooney s proposal now. Seems like a worthwile Q/A pair.

Comment: @PaulRooney Yep it's a useful resolution! Please post it;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro will not work since it is only performing simple text concatenation and substitution during the execution of the preprocessor, just before compilation.  The loop happens at runtime and so the value of `i` is not available during the preprocessor stage.

I'd suggest not using macros to try to automate work like this. It's hard to read and forces you to give your functions non-descriptive and difficult to differentiate between names.

You could achieve the same effect by just using a simple array literal. It's far clearer because, it doesn't require you to try and mentally picture what the macro substitutions look like when reading the code. It doesn't force you to use bad function names and also it allows you to search for the function names in the source code and see where they were used.

So instead

```
typedef <your-function-sig-here> handler_type;

handler_type handlers[] = 
{
    isr_1,
    isr_2,
    isr_3
};
```

256 entries represents quite a large array, but I think it's still worth doing it this way. There would be nothing stopping a different tool running before the compiler to generate the array in its own header, if you didn't mind the number based function names.